# Adding multiple web apps to firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-console

I working on a flutter project which requires 4 applications: 1 ios, 1 android and 2 web apps (users and admins). The ios and android comes from one flutter project. Then the two web apps are different flutter projects. I use flutter to add all the 3 apps currently.  I've successfully added all the applications expect the second web app. When i use flutter to add a second web app, It does not reflect on my projects apps. It still remains 3 apps instead of 4. Then I realize that the app id on the existing web app is the same id being printed to the terminal when i add the second.

Can some one explain to me what is going on?.